# Passing from AIR to javascript

Tags: flash, air, jplayer

Is there a way that I can pass the value of app: or appstorage: to a javascript file which has been included via URLRequest?

I have a web application with an HTML5 video player, and I've been asked to get it to work as an AIR app.  So far so good, except that there is a bug in jPlayer that requires you to use absolute file paths for media if you're using flash fallback.

I need to get the file path of the app: or appstorage: directory on a users machine, and pass that to javascript so that the player can find my videos.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way.  Setup a sandbox bridge.  See:  [Cross-scripting content in different security sandboxes](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/ProgrammingHTMLAndJavaScript_11.html#1036342) in the Adobe Flex 3 Help documents.

Comment: I'm trying to pass the actual location on the hard drive of the app: or appStorage: folder to a javascript file located in that same folder.  Do I need a sandbox bridge for that?  It seems like a relatively simple thing to do, but I've yet to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AIRAliases.js](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/devappshtml/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7fcd.html) which is in a folder in the Air SDK package, and "resolve" the path via Javascript like this:

`var path = air.File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("your/path/file.ext");`

or

```
var pathObj = air.File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("your/path/");
var path = pathObj.url;
```

so your file could be located via absolute path with something like:

```
path + "/file.ext"
```